# For a Map of Map<String, List<String>>, how would i print off elements with a list larger than x using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

So basically i have a Map which contains lists. for example

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("car", Arrays.asList("toyota", "bmw", "honda"));
data.put("fruit", Arrays.asList("apple","banana"));
data.put("computer", Arrays.asList("acer","asus","ibm"));
List<String> multipleVersions = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like a exeption thrown is lets say there are more than 2 elements in any given list so something like this

```
if(data.values().size() >= 3){
    System.out.println("multipbe versions exist" );
}
```

my question is how would i stream and filter out these elements greater than x and add it to the print statement?

i tried creating a new list and adding in these values

```
if (data.values().size() > 2){

     multipleVersions.add((data.values().stream().filter(val -> val.size() > 2)).toString());
 }
```

but when i go to print it out

```
multipleVersions.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

i get java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2@1b28cdfa

I know i need to read up on streams a bit more but can someone explain to me how to do this correctly and elegantly ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("car", Arrays.asList("toyota", "bmw", "honda"));
        data.put("fruit", Arrays.asList("apple","banana"));
        data.put("computer", Arrays.asList("acer","asus","ibm"));
        List<String> multipleVersions = new ArrayList<>();
       if (data.values().size() > 2){

            multipleVersions.add((data.values().stream().filter(val -> val.size() > 2)).toString());
        }



        if(data.values().size() >= 3){
            System.out.println("Over limit in the following " +  );
            System.out.println(multipleVersions.stream().toList())


        }
    }
```

expected to get Over limit in the following : Car , Computer

i can print of the lists like so

```
        System.out.println(data.values().stream().filter(val-> val.size() > 2).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

but still need to get the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like a exeption thrown is lets say there are more than 2 elements in any given list

You can iterate over the Values of the Map and pick the largest size using `mapToInt().max()`.

```
public static <K, V> int getMaxSize(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    
    return map.values().stream() // Stream<List<V>>
        .mapToInt(List::size)    // IntStream
        .max()                   // OptionalInt
        .orElse(0);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = // initializing the map
    
if (getMaxSize(data) > 2) {
    throw new MyException(); // choise the proper exception type
}
```

> I would like to do is essentially print out the keys with a value larger than `x`.

You can obtain all entries having list sizes greater than the given number in the following way:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> getGetEntriesLargerThen(Map<K, List<V>> map, int size) {
    
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > size)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue
        ));
}
```

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = // initializing the map

getGetEntriesLargerThen(data, 2)
            .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply! So what i would like to do is essentially print out the keys with a value larger than x. E.G if x is 2 than i would like to print out car and computer